# Using multiple authentication middlewares for one route

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I have a requirement where there is an API method (guarded by the well-known package `tymon/jwt-auth`) and I need to also be able to access it using the basic session based `web` middleware.

I don't want to repeat the route in both `api.php` and `web.php` even though that would totally work.

I tried adding both to the route but they simply don't work, like: `['auth:api', 'web']`
I also tried creating a new middleware with the intention of checking both `api` and `web` like so:

```
class CombinedAuth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $web = Auth::guard('web')->user();
        if ($web) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        $api = Auth::guard('api')->user();
        if ($api) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if(!$web && !$api) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }
    }
}
```

and that also doesn't work. The `api` middleware works fine but the `web` middleware doesn't and it always signs me out and redirects to the login page.

**So Is there a neat way of protecting a route with `api` and `web` middlewares at the same time in Laravel 5.8?**

Comment: write the code of the route you created with both middlewares

Comment: @GiacomoM I already wrote it. `['auth:api', 'web']` as the `middleware` value.

Comment: You did not write the exact route you created. Anyway try to put a dd inside the web middleware to see if its properly called or not.

Comment: @GiacomoM `web` middleware is built-in, I don't have access to the file.

Comment: Can I ask, Why you need a route have both api and web middleware? or you are just trying to get both apis and web routes work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `'auth:api,web'` to check for multiple guards.

Comment: I just tested this with Laravel 5.8 and it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple `can` middleware calls in Laravel 9 route;

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('money');
})
->middleware([
    'can:manage,App\Models\Payment', 
    'can:manage,App\Models\Withdraw',
]);


?>
```